# Possible to default DateTime column in Identity 2.0 Model to Null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a custom DateTime column in my User Profile. It is defined in the Identity Model like this:

```
public DateTime TemporaryPasswordIssueDateTime { get; set; }
```

It's defaulting to `1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM`. Is it possible to allow a DateTime column to default to `null`?

My purpose for this column is in Forgot Password. If a user forgets their password I am using `Membership.GeneratePassword()` to generate a temporary password which gets emailed to the user. I also update the PasswordHash and SecurityStamp. TemporaryPasswordIssueDateTime is set with the current DateTime.

When a user attempts to login, if TemporaryPasswordIssueDateTime is null they login normally using their username/password.

If TemporaryPasswordIssueDateTime is not null then the password is considered temporary and I check to see if it has expired. I could create a boolean to indicate the password is temporary, if I have to.

Is it possible for a DateTime column to be null in the AspNetUsers database table? If so, how would I set this in IdentityModel.cs?

**EDIT**

Making the DateTime column nullable with:

```
public DateTime? TemporaryPasswordIssueDateTime { get; set; }
```

Causes this line of code:

```
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - user.TemporaryPasswordIssueDateTime;
```

To throw this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.TimeSpan?' to 'System.TimeSpan'.
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

I already check for a null value prior to the TimeSpan ts = code.

Comment: I'm not on on a pc now but as far as I now, you can make every column nullable. Try the following: public DateTime ? TemporaryPasswordIssueDateTime { get; set; } Notice the question mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's defaulting to `1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM`. Is it possible to allow a DateTime column to default to null?

Yes, map it to a nullable DateTime:

```
public DateTime? TemporaryPasswordIssueDateTime { get; set; }
```

But you'll have to make sure it's also ALLOW NULL in the database and that all other layers play along. `1/1/1900` is not the `null` value for dates in .NET. That is `default(DateTime)` or `DateTime.MinValue`.

Comment: Henk, I edited my question. I'm not sure how it needs to be referenced in code without throwing an error now. I tried a couple of ideas, but they didn't resolve the error.

Comment: use `DateTime.Now - user.TemporaryPasswordIssueDateTime.Value;` after making sure it's not `null`.

Comment: Instead of using `null` in my logic maybe I should just check for `1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM` - or, maybe I need to create a boolean column for this...